# Resize Image after dragdrop according to container in Flex 4

Tags: flex4, drag-and-drop

I am using Flash builder and i am drag drop the image into different size of containers i want to resize the image after drop inside the container according to it's container with maintaing it's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Use `percentWidth` and `percentHeight` properties. Set them to 100. Also set the image.[maintainAspectRatio](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#maintainAspectRatio) to true.

Comment: Thanx Ranhiru Cooray but when i set percentWidth and percentHeight to 100 it add some dummy area on left or bottom.

Comment: Well that is because the aspect ratio is unchanged :)